# Dual Boot: Directly booting to Xubuntu without giving me option to boot Ubuntu MATE

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, xubuntu, gparted

I first installed Xubuntu in my laptop. I then installed Ubuntu MATE choosing the option 'Something else' in the installer to create manual partitions. I created a 60GB space for / and 30GB space for /home and successfully installed Ubuntu MATE.
But now the problem is every time I startup the system it takes me to Xubuntu and does not give me any option to which OS I should boot.
I have the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te2R4.png).

/dev/sda5 was created as / (with 60GB space)
and /dev/sda6 was created as /home (with 30GB space) for installing Ubuntu MATE. Other partitions were all created while installing Xubuntu.

Comment: try changing GRUB TIME OUT in /etc/default/grub  to a non zero value